# New Google Custom Search Api Results - PHP

Tags: php, api

So the new Google custom Search has rolled out and im having trouble displaying the results...

I am using php to return the results in json and am getting a invalid argument in for each error... Here is what i am using...

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=test&callback=json";
$results = file_get_contents($url);

foreach ($results->items as $r)
{

}
```

Here's the callback when I go to the URL in the browser:

```
json({
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q\u003d{searchTerms}&num\u003d{count?}&start\u003d{startIndex?}&hr\u003d{language?}&safe\u003d{safe?}&cx\u003d{cx?}&cref\u003d{cref?}&sort\u003d{sort?}&alt\u003djson"
 },
 "queries": {
  "nextPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - test",
    "totalResults": 276000000,
    "searchTerms": "test",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 11,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve"
   }
  ],
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - test",
    "totalResults": 276000000,
    "searchTerms": "test",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve"
   }
  ]
 },
 "context": {
  "title": "Curriculum",
  "facets": [
   [
    {
     "label": "lectures",
     "anchor": "Lectures"
    }
   ],
   [
    {
     "label": "assignments",
     "anchor": "Assignments"
    }
   ],
   [
    {
     "label": "reference",
     "anchor": "Reference"
    }
   ]
  ]
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Lecture 8: Pseudo Randomness and the Next-bit test 1 Review 2 ...",
   "htmlTitle": "Lecture 8: Pseudo Randomness and the Next-bit \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e 1 Review 2 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs687/2008sp/scribes/scribe19Feb2008.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.cornell.edu",
   "snippet": "Feb 19, 2008 ... Definition 2 An ensemble {Xn} passes the Next Bit test ⇐⇒ ∀ PPT A, ... Next   Bit test. We have to now prove the other direction. ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Feb 19, 2008 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Definition 2 An ensemble {Xn} passes the Next Bit \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e ⇐⇒ ∀ PPT A, \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Next \u003cbr\u003e  Bit \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e. We have to now prove the other direction. \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "ErjWs7c3umEJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "producer": "MiKTeX pdfTeX-1.40.4",
      "creator": "TeX",
      "creationdate": "D:20080306114145-05'00'",
      "moddate": "D:20080306114145-05'00'",
      "fullbanner": "This is MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.7.2808 (1.40.4)"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "General Information for Computer Science 227 and 228 Test-Out ...",
   "htmlTitle": "General Information for Computer Science 227 and 228 \u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e-Out \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.iastate.edu/gradadm/cmarquar/testout.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.iastate.edu",
   "snippet": "should fill out an application for a test-out in the main office and find ... \"  Students may ordinarily attempt a CBE test only once in any course or area. ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "should fill out an application for a \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e-out in the main office and find \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e &quot;\u003cbr\u003e  Students may ordinarily attempt a CBE \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e only once in any course or area. \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "HvE3JGhnVkgJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "creationdate": "D:20091006145719-05'00'",
      "author": "prabhu",
      "creator": "PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2",
      "producer": "Acrobat Distiller 7.0 (Windows)",
      "moddate": "D:20091006145719-05'00'"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "CS1130 Grades/exams/assignments",
   "htmlTitle": "CS1130 Grades/exams/assignments",
   "link": "http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs1130/2010fa/gradesexams.html",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.cornell.edu",
   "snippet": "There will be two tests. The exams require mastery of the material: you will be   expected to get 85% on each test. If you get lower than 85% on a test, ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "There will be two \u003cb\u003etests\u003c/b\u003e. The exams require mastery of the material: you will be \u003cbr\u003e  expected to get 85% on each \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e. If you get lower than 85% on a \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e, \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "fjSAJnTr0FgJ"
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Lecture 16: Recognition II Outline Model-based recognition ...",
   "htmlTitle": "Lecture 16: Recognition II Outline Model-based recognition \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/courses/378/slides/lecture16.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.utexas.edu",
   "snippet": "Hypothesize and test. • Given model of object .... Hypothesize and test: looking   for object and ... “Test” as function of these representations that ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Hypothesize and \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e. • Given model of object \u003cb\u003e....\u003c/b\u003e Hypothesize and \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e: looking \u003cbr\u003e  for object and \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e “\u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e” as function of these representations that \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "_QUgy1DsMFgJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "creationdate": "D:20071108175221-06'00'",
      "author": "grauman",
      "creator": "PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2",
      "producer": "Acrobat Distiller 8.1.0 (Windows)",
      "moddate": "D:20071108175221-06'00'"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Notes on the Miller-Rabin randomized primality test",
   "htmlTitle": "Notes on the Miller-Rabin randomized primality \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs482/2008sp/handouts/mrpt.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.cornell.edu",
   "snippet": "Apr 25, 2008 ... test whether a number is prime. It is called the Miller-Rabin primality .... The   Miller-Rabin test is based on a third way to prove that a ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Apr 25, 2008 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e whether a number is prime. It is called the Miller-Rabin primality \u003cb\u003e....\u003c/b\u003e The \u003cbr\u003e  Miller-Rabin \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e is based on a third way to prove that a \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "IP9TrtclTpAJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "producer": "pdfTeX-1.40.3",
      "creator": "TeX",
      "creationdate": "D:20080424173852-04'00'",
      "moddate": "D:20080424173852-04'00'",
      "fullbanner": "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6) kpathsea version 3.5.6"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "TOWARD A THEORY OF TEST DATA SELECTION John B. Go0denough Susan L ...",
   "htmlTitle": "TOWARD A THEORY OF \u003cb\u003eTEST\u003c/b\u003e DATA SELECTION John B. Go0denough Susan L \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/VandV/criteria.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.umd.edu",
   "snippet": "Formal Definitions and the Fundamental Theorem of Testing criterion is reliable   if and only if ... set of test data, i. e. , if it can be shown that for ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Formal Definitions and the Fundamental Theorem of \u003cb\u003eTesting\u003c/b\u003e criterion is reliable \u003cbr\u003e  if and only if \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e set of \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e data, i. e. , if it can be shown that for \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "44B1_Z8kNHYJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "moddate": "D:20010115130600-05'00'",
      "creationdate": "D:20010114103427-05'00'"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Lecture Notes 16 - pmwiki - Main.homepage",
   "htmlTitle": "Lecture Notes 16 - pmwiki - Main.homepage",
   "link": "http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs467/2008f/attach/ln16.html",
   "displayLink": "zoo.cs.yale.edu",
   "snippet": "Nov 3, 2008 ... If n is prime, the test always fails by Theorem 1 of section 68. ... The test μa  (n) is based on computing a sequence b0,b1,…,bs of integers ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Nov 3, 2008 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e If n is prime, the \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e always fails by Theorem 1 of section 68. \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e The \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e μa\u003cbr\u003e  (n) is based on computing a sequence b0,b1,…,bs of integers \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "TnMAQxlY3HIJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "originator": "TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)",
      "src": "ln16.tex",
      "date": "2008-11-11 16:55:00"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "CS 337 Test 3 5/5/06 Open book and notes. Max points \u003d 50 Time ...",
   "htmlTitle": "CS 337 \u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e 3 5/5/06 Open book and notes. Max points \u003d 50 Time \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/Classes.dir/337quizSoln.dir/S06.quiz3.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.utexas.edu",
   "snippet": "Test 3. 5/5/06. Open book and notes. Max points \u003d 50. Time \u003d 50 min. Do all   questions. 1. (Relational Algebra; 15 points) ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e 3. 5/5/06. Open book and notes. Max points \u003d 50. Time \u003d 50 min. Do all \u003cbr\u003e  questions. 1. (Relational Algebra; 15 points) \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "ClTLaytSRUIJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "creator": "TeX output 2006.05.04:1646",
      "producer": "dvipdfm 0.13.2c, Copyright Š 1998, by Mark A. Wicks",
      "creationdate": "D:20060504164645-06'00'"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "EE410 Test Structures & Testing",
   "htmlTitle": "EE410 \u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e Structures &amp; \u003cb\u003eTesting\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee410/TestStructures.pdf",
   "displayLink": "www.stanford.edu",
   "snippet": "Test every unique structure at least once, but don't waste time testing .....   Take good care of the testing setup — it's your only one and it cannot ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e every unique structure at least once, but don&#39;t waste time \u003cb\u003etesting\u003c/b\u003e \u003cb\u003e.....\u003c/b\u003e \u003cbr\u003e  Take good care of the \u003cb\u003etesting\u003c/b\u003e setup — it&#39;s your only one and it cannot \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "YKadfqMlYuIJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "author": "Krishna Saraswat",
      "producer": "Mac OS X 10.6.6 Quartz PDFContext",
      "creator": "Microsoft PowerPoint",
      "creationdate": "D:20110209003235Z00'00'",
      "moddate": "D:20110209003235Z00'00'"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "SIP: Interoperability Test Event FAQ",
   "htmlTitle": "SIP: Interoperability \u003cb\u003eTest\u003c/b\u003e Event FAQ",
   "link": "http://www.cs.columbia.edu/sip/sipit/faq.html",
   "displayLink": "www.cs.columbia.edu",
   "snippet": "\"The interoperability test event is for non-competitve, friendly testing of ...   It is meant as someplace people can come to, and test their code at, ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "&quot;The interoperability \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e event is for non-competitve, friendly \u003cb\u003etesting\u003c/b\u003e of \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e \u003cbr\u003e  It is meant as someplace people can come to, and \u003cb\u003etest\u003c/b\u003e their code at, \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "m7jgghXfi78J",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "author": "Henning Schulzrinne"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

`$results = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));`

To be able to correctly decode the response of the service, you may do the following:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$start = 'json(';
$end = ');';

$substr_start_pos = strpos($json, $start) + strlen($start);
$substr_length = strlen($json) - $substr_start_pos - (strlen($json) - strrpos($json, $end));

$json = substr($json, $substr_start_pos, $substr_length);

$results = json_decode($json);
```

This may be a bit confusing, but I did this for the following reasons:

- The sample response you provided, has a 'json(' string before the actual JSON, and a ');' after it, which can't be decoded with PHP's json_decode.
- Simple replacing won't be good, because the actual JSON might contain these substrings as well.

Comment: You generally want to test you have a non-empty string returned prior to passing it to json_decode() to avoid PHP warnings.

Comment: You're right. Moreover, there are far better methods to fetch response from an URL than file_get_contents. I just demonstrated the concept.

Comment: The reason your getting a bad request is because i have not included my key in the url and instead used "MYKEY" which obviously is not a real key. I also have changed the code to [code]$results = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));[/code] and get the same error.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you could show us a sample response from Google to a valid request

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS TRUE SIMPLE PHP DECODE WILL NOT HELP YOU,
TRY THIS
`$data = html_entity_decode($url);`
I am sure this will work properly
to try later var dump the date to check the results.